# Multiline bootstrap split button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bootstrap split button where the button label spans multiple lines. However, the caret appears on a new line, while I want it to appear on the right side of the button. The caret part should span the whole height of the button and the caret itself should appear on the bottom. Is this possible?

Here is my attempt:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn" style="white-space: normal">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed faucibus imperdiet placerat. Aliquam sodales sem vel scelerisque cursus. Maecenas et risus dui. Morbi rutrum sagittis tortor, et dignissim felis sodales id. Donec auctor nulla tincidunt eros maximus ultricies. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse tristique felis sit amet dui auctor, et accumsan risus egestas  
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span> 
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    <li><a href>Option 1</li>
    <li><a href>Option 2</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7dkq7ha/1/

Comment: Personally I would strongly advise against having so much text in a button.

Comment: that button is huge!

Comment: i agree with @DavidG
Too much text in the button tag
u might want to shorten the text or `overflow:hidden`